# Cannot combine custom titles with other titles features error

Tags: android

I have a tabhost and there is an activity inside. I want this activity to have customized title bar so I used the following code. But it gives the error Cannot combine custom titles with other titles features. I look at the file and see only one theme applied to it, I am not sure why this is happening... Any idea? I am also using dialogtheme for other activities in my tabhost, but I think that is fine because I am applying my custom theme only to one Activity(which is named startActivity).

Manifest:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainTabActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"   //this is the Custom title bar theme for this activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Activity onCreate():

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);  //error happned here
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
    setContentView(R.layout.startactivity);
```

window_title.xml in layout folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:background="#323331">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, the @style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```