# Tabhost title error ("you cannot combine custom titles with other title features")

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-component

I have a tabhost in one of my screen and I did a custom title in same screen. Now I want to add a button in custom title but I am getting "you cannot combine custom titles with other title features" error. I try ed all situation like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686556/try-to-use-window-feature-custom-title-but-got-exceptionyou-cannot-combine-cust) but it doesn't work for me.

My code is :

```
requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE );
    setContentView(R.layout.routes);        
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.customtitle);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I tried this code other screen(this is not include tabhost) it is worked. What is wrong? Can anybody help me?

**EDIT:**

```
  <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">#084B8A</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">65dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
  </style>
```

**AND IN MY MANIFEST:** `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"`

I didnt write any code snippet in Java class.I just declare like that.Maybe it is not right? Possible?

Comment: you should setContentView AFTER you call super.onCreate

Comment: Anyway, you should ALWAYS do that.

Answer (score 0):

Does your activity extend Activity or TabActivity?