# android - combine ActionBar and a custom TitleBar?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I'm creating an application for android 4.0 and above. I use the Holo.Light theme with dark `ActionBar` (`Tabs` as navigation mode).

The problem: there are too many icons (tabs) I'd need to place into the ActionBar, so I'm thinking about creating a custom `TitleBar` and placing some `Buttons` there to keep the functionality whilst not overspamming the `ActionBar`. 
I tried the following:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
```

This causes the app to crash with following message:

```
08:00:24.063: E/AndroidRuntime(11283): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.maver1ck.test/net.maver1ck.test.Main}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

What are "other title features"? Is that possible to use the ActionBar and a custom title?

Comment: The Activity class forces calling setContentView() must be placed after calling requestWindowFeature() in onCreate(). Crashes may be due to this reason. Did you checked it?

Comment: sure. I edited the question for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

This is not so good idea to combine such bars. Insted of it use custom layout only.

Comment: can you explain why that is not a good idea? In terms of usability that would be comfortable for the user to have some quick access in the titlebar..

Comment: IMHO, if I was going to customise the top navigation bar and would write my own ot avoid "hard to find bugs". Hope this'll help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805361/setting-a-window-feature-custom-title-creates-androidruntimeexception/13806493#13806493

Comment: well referring to this question it looks like that is not possible to use the ActionBar and a custom titleBar? But you can use the default (pretty ugly) Activity's titleBar.. Had to manually remove it.

Comment: I'm working on outsource project right now. And the realization of the title bar totally custom. They have removed standart title bar and develop custom as custom view. It's very useful IMHO.

Comment: ah, slowly I'm getting what you mean. But you can't actually position your View above the ActionBar, or..?

Comment: No, you can't position you custom action bar above standart. You should remove standartr action bar