# Android custom title bar

Tags: android, custom-titlebar, android-titlebar

I have been trying to do my custom title bar for a week.

I have tried approximately 30 suggestions to achieve that but nothing worked.

I get the `you cannot combine custom titles with other title features` error every time whatever I try. I can't get rid of this error. This driving me mad.

I have also tried to find a solution by looking for the error on Google. It also did not work.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_title);
```

I don't know how to achieve a custom title bar.

Much thanks for helps in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best way to do it in my opinion.

You should do, in res/values/styles.xml, something like:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="...">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="mActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">...</item>
        <item name="android:icon">...</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">...</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What is the best way in your opinion?

Comment: To use styles.xml as I wrote

Comment: How to customize (add textview, imageview etc.) with this way?

Comment: Are you talking about the left icon and the associated title? You should also read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: I am talking about putting search, refresh icons and handling their click events.

Comment: Ok so read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html and this http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/handling-options-menu-item-selections-in-android/

Comment: I am wondering what's the main difference between ActionBar and TitleBar. How to decide to use which is better. Maybe it's mentioned in that article. If it's not, I will ask it :) Thanks for your helps. By the way, I changed color of title bar with code you provided. But it changed whole color system. I don't know why.

Comment: TitleBar is the old title bar used before Android 3.0, now it's called ActionBar and it's pretty different. Use the android:background inside your ActionBar style, not your application style, as I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same error while implementing a custom title bar..."you cannot combine custom titles with other title features"

According to [You cannot combine custom title with other title features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171373/you-cannot-combine-custom-title-with-other-title-features), Holo's title bar is displayed if the project uses Holo theme.

I stripped my project of all code that uses Holo, and after that my custom title bar displayed.