# Android theme won't apply to activity

Tags: android, user-interface, themes, android-manifest

When I set the background color in the layout everything works perfectly. However, **when I try to set the it from a theme it won't work.** It seems I'm doing something wrong. Here is the code.

**Manifest:**

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.somma.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/custom_title_theme"
    >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**custom_title_theme.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="custom_title_theme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@drawable/custom_title_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/Meerenguee</item>
</style>    
</resources>
```

Is that because in every class I call these lines onStart()?

```
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
      setContentView(com.example.somma.R.layout.sumwindow);
      getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);
```

**custom_title_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/custom_title_background">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:textColor="@color/cream_brown"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:id="@+id/custom_title_text"
          android:text="@string/app_name"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
          android:shadowRadius="3"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/settings_button" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:text="@string/settings"
android:onClick="openSharedPref"
android:background="@drawable/header_button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar); prevents "custom_title_theme" from being set?

Here is a screen of how everything appears:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try following:

```
<application 
   android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   android:theme="@style/custom_title_theme"/>
```

Comment: the same here. If  I do that I got this error "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/ custom_title_theme')."

Comment: Now I get "You cannot combine custom title with other title features"

Comment: Ok I found the answer for the bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171373/you-cannot-combine-custom-title-with-other-title-features

Comment: I did as you said but I had to create a different custom_title_style for API 11 
<resources>
    <style name="custom_title_theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@drawable/custom_title_background</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/Meerenguee</item>
    </style>    
 
</resources> and now it works as a charm! Thank you very much

Comment: ok, I m glad that you got your answer. But a friendly suggestion, from next time onwards kindly provide as much details as possible with your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that! Now that I read my question again I realize it lacks important informations.

Answer (score 1):

Add theme into your android manifeast file.

Your are missing @android:style.

use

```
android:theme="@android:style/custom_title_theme" instead of 
android:theme="@style/custom_title_theme"
```

Comment: I think I did it in the part "<activity android:name="com.example.somma.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/custom_title_theme"
    >"
Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Sorry it seems I can't followyou. Use what instead of what?

Comment: use @android:style not@style

Comment: If I do that I got the error "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/
 custom_title_theme')."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36265/discussion-between-pinolo-and-mohammod-hossain)