# Apply configChanges to every activity or apply it programmatically?

Tags: android

I wnat to  apply theme  , so  I  quote  it  on  Application or Some  Activity tag, but  neighther  Application tag  nor  Activity tag  work.  how  can  I  apply it?
Mainifest.xml:

```
 <application
    android:name=".base.CustomApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Activity_Base_Setting">

    <!-- android key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.max_aspect"
        android:value="2.1"/>

    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard"
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Activity_Base_Setting">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:name=".ui.activity.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

values/styles.xml

```
<style name="Activity_Base_Setting" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:launchMode">singleTop</item>
    <item name="android:configChanges">screenSize|keyboard|orientation</item>
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
</style>
```

I don't want write it  like this  ,

```
  <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android theme won't apply to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445550/android-theme-wont-apply-to-activity)

Comment: No, different.  the question talking about  setting like "launch mode, orientation,config" different with “UI theme” , I  saw some blog it work when apply  UI theme,   and  I  also  want  know  why won't apply activity  and wont' apply  application