# CustomTitle for MvxTabsFragmentActivity

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I was wondering if there is presently a way in MVVMCross to do a custom title bar on the MvxTabsFragmentActivity?

I'm using the MvxTabsFragmentActivity to implement the ActionBar.  In all of the documentation I've seen you need to request this feature in the OnCreate method of the activity.

When I try to do this:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);
    base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
}
```

I get an error that says "You cannot combine custom titles with other title features."  When it hits:

```
base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
```

I've tried doing base.RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle) but I get the same error.

I'm not seeing anything in MvxTabsFragmentActivity that does anything with the title bar...  Has anyone else tried to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This error message has lots of questions and answers already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197345/cannot-combine-custom-titles-with-other-title-features - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171373/you-cannot-combine-custom-title-with-other-title-features - http://bit.ly/15vEcjc

Comment: Yea I know, I saw most of those.  This seems to be an issue inherent with MvxTabsFragmentActivity.  My first mistake was putting the RequestWindowFeature call after base.OnCreate, which those answers describe.  When I moved it to be the first call I expected it to allow me to use the RequestWIndowFeature however something in MvxTabsFragmentActivity is doing something with the Title Bar.  Looking at the code I don't see what could be causing it...

Comment: Nevermind I see what you are saying now.  This is because of the Holo theme... Thanks!  If you want to repost I can mark as an answer!