# android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi in my code getting error. Can you tell me how to fix the issue.

**Style  Code**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

**Activity code**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // To set the custom title with Button
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_account_screen_1);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
    R.layout.title_layout_with_two_button);

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle)).setText(R.string.create_acc);
//  ((Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button)).setText(R.string.login);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.right_button)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**Manifest code**

```
<activity android:name=".CreateAccountActivity1" 
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

** create_account_screen_1**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#fafafa"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"  />


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp" 
                android:id="@+id/scrollview_bottom">
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/step_1_2"  
                    android:visibility="gone"   />
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="whatsThisClick"
                    android:text="@string/what_this"
                    android:visibility="gone" />


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView            
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="280sp"
                android:paddingTop="5sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/user_name"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/user_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp" 
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rouned_corner"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/dob"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"  />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/dobText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:hint="@string/dateMMDDYYYY"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp" 
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rouned_corner"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" > <!-- android:onClick="onDobTextClick" -->
                </EditText>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/password"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"  />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp" 
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rouned_corner"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
                </EditText>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/conform_password"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/conform_password"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp" 
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rouned_corner"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >
                </EditText>



            </LinearLayout>



            </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fafafa"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"    
        >
       <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"  />

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#fafafa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"        
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"    >

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                    android:onClick="next"
                    android:text="@string/next"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/default_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />



        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

the above code is my layout file.

**log-cat error**

```
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.velantech.activity/com.velantech.activity.ForgotUserIDActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:227)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2601)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2844)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:252)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at com.velantech.activity.ForgotUserIDActivity.onCreate(ForgotUserIDActivity.java:54)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    12-09 23:42:21.750: E/AndroidRuntime(10108):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your `log-cat` Error.

Comment: @Yugesh.. hi i'm add my log-car error.

Comment: hi.. @Yugesh... im change the activity name ForgotUserIDActivity.. the above code activity is .CreateAccountActivity1.

Comment: Refer this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197345/cannot-combine-custom-titles-with-other-title-features)

Comment: post this layout file: create_account_screen_1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The theme you are using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` contains this definition (in its parent):

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

So the theme says that it has no title and you are tyring to use a custom title. This is incompatible.

The theme you are using contains an action bar, and the title in the action bar is handled differently. See [Styling the Action Bar.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

---

**EDIT: Suggestion for light theme without action bar**

To get a "light" theme without the action bar (so you can use custom title), this should work:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: ..Please refer the [link](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/creating-a-custom-title-bar/) .. my code like this. can you tell me how can i change theme  ** Theme.AppCompat.Light **

Comment: If you aren't using the action bar, just replace  `parent="AppTheme.Base"` with `parent="android:Theme"` in your `style` declaration for `AppTheme`.

Comment: I have changed but it showing same as previous design theme it doesn't show the Light version theme like white color alert backgrounds.

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer. Try that.

Comment: Do you need to use the compatibility library for this? What version of Android do you need to support?

Comment: Yes, I have added compatibility library new appcompact-V7 in my project to work on android API version 7 to Update version 21, all API support same light version theme, all version themes works on material theme.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I'm tried but still not solve this problem, i have the same error while compiling the update theme.

Comment: What changes did you end up making?

Comment: I have used the two different theme like starting application run one theme and all activity runs on another theme, I,m modified the activity theme its working correctly.and also previously im used the _<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">_ this style, now i,m use _<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">_ this style.

Comment: @DavidWasser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157222/how-to-change-action-bar-background-and-text-colors