# Android Lollipop theme compatibility All API Version [ 7- 21]

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi I'm using Lollipop theme for all other API version, but i don't use Lollipop toolbar and style actions. I have created a `ActionBar` like custom `ActionBar` layout like left and right corner Buttons and title is in center.

Here the my the theme but it doesnot work. can you update this issue. also tell me the style for "Theme.AppCompat.Light"

// Style code

res/values/theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

values-v21/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

// Activity code like.

```
public class CreateAccountActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // To set the custom title with Button
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_account_screen_1);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.title_layout_with_two_button);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle)).setText(R.string.create_acc);
//      ((Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button)).setText(R.string.login);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.right_button))
                .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



}
```

Comment: What is not working? Can you show some logs?

Comment: Can you see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395263/android-util-androidruntimeexception-you-cannot-combine-custom-titles-with-othe), this is for actual issue.