# How to change action bar background and text colors

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer from this tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

and i am trying to change action bar background from this selected answer

[Set title background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color)

but when i run my app app got crash and shows error

**Manifest**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="Login_Page"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        >


    </activity>

    <activity android:name="Register"></activity>
    <activity android:name="SplashActivity"
                    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

        >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>        
</application>
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
```

**LogCat**

> 07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}:
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles
>   with other title features 07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 07-01
>   12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-01
>   12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-01 12:57:38.882:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 07-01
>   12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-01
>   12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-01 12:57:38.882:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 07-01
>   12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-01 12:57:38.882:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14690): Caused by:
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles
>   with other title features 07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):
>     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:245)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2701)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2921)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835) 07-01
>   12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):    at
>   info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470) 07-01
>   12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
>   07-01 12:57:38.882: E/AndroidRuntime(14690):  ... 11 more 07-01
>   12:57:38.892: E/AlarmManagerService(378):
>   android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 51461.572000000
>   07-01 12:57:38.892: V/AlarmManager(378): waitForAlarm result :8 07-01
>   12:57:38.902: E/android.os.Debug(378): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t
>   -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error

Style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
        <item name="android:background">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>   
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/titletextcolor</item>                
    </style>
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>



</resources>
```

Comment: share `AppTheme` xml code please

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19592911/1479511) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color/13333661#13333661)

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra i add this getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "</font>"));..and still text color is black

Comment: what about the other link, I provided?

Comment: @Roman can you share code of your `AppTheme` from styles.xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in `styles.xml`:

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.


        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF00</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Remove these two lines:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
```

It will work for you.

Comment: but in my splash activity i dont want any title or action bar..and splash is work fine app crahs on mainactivity..did you check log cat pastie??

Comment: can you share full style.xml??

Comment: i think the code i added in main activity is not needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82078/discussion-between-anand-singh-and-roman).

Comment: tell me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847086/how-to-attach-jpg-or-png-file-to-gmail-or-facebook