# Exception on using custom title bar android

Tags: java, android, custom-titlebar

I have been trying using custom title bar in my activity. Following is the code i have used

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    if ( customTitleSupported ) {
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);
    }
    final TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    if ( txtTitle != null ) {
        txtTitle.setText("PikMyBox - Welcome to PikMyBox");
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

**custom_title_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtCustomText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorSplash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    -----
```

I m getting the following error when activity executed

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:302)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2975)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3241)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1821)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:363)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:229)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:184)
                  at com.kommlabs.pikmybox.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395263/android-util-androidruntimeexception-you-cannot-combine-custom-titles-with-othe possible duplicate

Comment: @Raghunandan it does not show any exception now, but it shows both custom title bar and default title bar on screen

Comment: @Raghunandan I also getting `final TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);` as null. why ?

Comment: Why don't use a toolbar? Its a view group and you can customize it

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks,  i have manage it with using toolbar..

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:windowNoTitle` to `false` in your styles.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is below `final TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);` ie why you are getting exception.You are initilizing the view before it is been created.

Change it to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 final TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
```

Also in case of your exception with custom title bar use this style

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

As suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27410003/3111083