# Show title bar from code

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, titlebar, android-titlebar

In the manifest file I have this line to my application tag

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

and basically every activity doesn't have a title bar, but for one of the activities I want to show the title bar

I know that to hide the bar I can use this code

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

How can I show title bar from code ?

**EDIT**
PLEASE do not tall me how can I hide the title bar :), I know that, if anybody know how can I show it ?

I know that I can put NoTitleBar in every activity that I want to hide and I can leave it for the one I want to be shown... But that was not my point

Comment: This is a good question!  I don't see anything that will let you stuff it back in once removed.  Maybe use the requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

Comment: @JPM it will crush i guess

Comment: You ned to handle displaying and hiding title bar in the Activity itself instead of setting the `theme` for it in the manifest

Answer (score 6):

For me thous lines of code work perfectly:

Hide:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Show:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

in each activity except the activity where you want to show the title. Dont use this theme in `application` attribute

according to your comment  you want to make my change to only one place and it seems you dont want to make the chage in only one manifest(!). anywayy you can do another thing

use a BaseActivity Class where use the no title feature and extend it in all classes except the titled activity.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is to reference this [Try to use Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8634785/346309)

Apparently this doesn't work and any other way seems to always crash

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.settings);
activity.setTitle("Settings");
```

I am sure this is the way to do this via code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below line to hide in your activity's OnCreate method
Java: this.getSupportActionBar().hide();

Android:  this.supportActionBar?.hide();